# CSV Querying in C# using LINQtoCSV

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning C# and I followed a [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) to which I am successful to use my CSV file and I can query the file properly.

```
var productsNetherlands =
    from p in products
    where p.Country == "Netherlands"
    select new { p.Name, p.LaunchDate, p.Price, p.Description };
```

In the code above, I am filtering "Netherlands". My question is how can I use variable in that part instead of hardcoding the "Netherlands"?

For example:

```
var productsNetherlands =
    from p in products
    where p.Country == s_variable
    select new { p.Name, p.LaunchDate, p.Price, p.Description };
```

where my s_variable is

```
string s_variable = "Netherlands";
```

Error shows up "Error   4   The name 's_variable ' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Your example using `s_variable` should work fine.  Have you tried it?

Comment: What you wrote should work fine. Are you having a problem with this code?

Comment: yes. Error shows up "The name s_variable  does not exist in the current context"

Comment: make sure it's in scope and declared above linq

Comment: Thanks, I made it public instead and it worked fine. I declared the s_variable above the query though but it didnt work, so I made it public instead.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the given query provider simply doesn't support this.  Most other mainstream query providers will notice a variable usage such as that, evaluate it to its value and then use that value as if it were a constant.  For whatever reason, this particular query provider is choosing not to do that.

The ideal solution would be to simply improve the query provider for it to handle this situation.  That may or may not be an option for you in particular though.

One option you *do* have is to write a method yourself that takes the expression you *want* to use and compiles it down to an expression that the query provider can understand.

To cover your equals expression we can use a custom `Equals` method:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Equal<TSource, TKey>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> expression, TKey value)
{
    var body = Expression.Equal(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, expression.Parameters[0]);
}
```

Which could be used like so:

```
var productsNetherlands = products.Where(
    Equal<Product>(p => p.Country, s_variable))
    .Select(p => [...]);
```

Comment: ok. im lost. did I mention I was a beginner? :D thank you for this